# Configure linux server to allow Wordpress to auto generage wp-config

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-12.04

How can I configure my VPS to allow for auto generation of wp-config.php during installation?

I gave full permissions to everything to see if that was the cause, but that didn't do it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm on Ubuntu

Comment: are you getting an error message? what are the permissions on wp-config.php?

Comment: I go through setup and at the end it takes me to a window asking to do it again because it can't find wp-config.php, I gave full permissions to all files. It just doesn't create the configured wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the VPS for auto generation of wp-config.php then just extract the wordpress file to your /var/www directory. Then make a database for wordpress after that go to youdomain.com/wordpress(assuming that the extracted wordpress has created a wordpress folder). Then you will find general setup options like database info, this will auto generate wp-config.php for you automatically.

If you want to configure wp-config.php manually : http://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wpmu-and-buddypress-installation-2/creating-and-editing-your-wp-config-php-file/